# Diffrence between 合唱, 唱和 and 斉唱

Tags: meaning, word-choice, words, nouns

I know all of 合唱, 唱和 and 斉唱 mean chorus/choir but are there any differences between them?

Answer (score 1):

- 唱和 - sing a song all together / respond (in ceremony)
- 合唱 - sing a song in chorus (bass, tenor, alto and soprano)
- 斉唱 - sing a song in unison